# How to check API call requests from perticular user in salesforce on daily basis?

Tags: api, governorlimits, limits

Is there any way in salesforce we can measure/check how many API calls specific user consumed/made?

we need this to identify if any integration user is eating up most of the API calls and is there any room for improvement there ?

Note: I am aware that at the company level we can check what overall usage is.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is any direct link by which u can check this info via Code. But I believe you can do something in latest salesforce platform release via Analytic API.

There is a report named "API Usage Last 7 Days" under "Administrative Reports" folder and you should be able to run this report via Code and get the desired data you want.

Comment: I cannot see this report in my org, we have unlimited edition and I am system Admin, is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Look up into the folder titled "Administrative Reports". It should be the first report in the folder.